# Average of AC signal measured with oscilloscope

Tags: ac, oscilloscope, ripple

I'm wondering why the oscilloscope displays that average rectifier ripple voltage value measured in AC mode is higher than zero. Moreover, the minimum value happens also to be higher than zero. Shouldn't average value equals or be very close to zero?

Is it for sure my own mistake or there is some explanation? Thank you a lot in advance.

Comment: Could you supply a picture?

Comment: Only symmetrical waveforms will have average value equal to zero. The rectifier ripple voltage for sure is not a symmetrical, so the average is higher than zero . https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier#Full-wave_rectification

Comment: @G36 the question also said that the minimum value was above zero implying something is very wrong.

Comment: vertical offset?

Comment: Yes, I know that average value of the rectifier output voltage is higher than zero, but I meant the average value of ripples measured in AC mode. Isn't it so that oscilloscope cut out the dc value leaving only ac signal which is centered on its average?


And here is a picture.

That's a bridge rectifier with 
filtering capacitor 1µF and load 100kΩ.

Input voltage: 10 Vpp, 300Hz 

[link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0iloOJGx8VdNDdmb1gxYUs4QlE)

Comment: Did you give the scope trace a chance to settle down after the target circuit was initially powered up?

Comment: Yes, it was connected to function generator all the time. I made some other measurements, the AC average keeps staying around 25 mV whilst the minimum value changes sensibly (the higher frequency, the less ripple peak-to-peak value), but there is always 25 mV too high.

Comment: Your link shows an AC waveform with amplitude of about 20mVpp. Is this what you mean by 'AC average', or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Scopes have a time constant around 1 second, and you are looking at about 20 ms. Try looking at with .5 sec per division and see if there is not a ripple at lower frequency.  You can also check for amplifier offset by setting the trigger to AC and normal mode, and put the trigger level at zero.  If you don't trigger, the signal is never passing through zero so you have amplifier offset and scope error at this small signal.